# Uncharted 3 multiplayer online: DLC maps never play

Tags: uncharted-3

I bought, downloaded, and installed a DLC map pack for Uncharted 3. But though I've spent hours playing online, I have never seen one of the new maps come up in voting. I have the DLC option turned on.

I tried creating a custom game, and there, I'm able to select the new maps -- but it's pretty boring being the only player in the game. Can I open my custom game to the public?

Answer (score 1):

Back in 2013 when you wrote this, the DLC maps were all, as you've said, exclusive to the people who've bought them. So in order to play them you need to have EVERYONE in your match own the maps. Now, since Naughty Dog noticed this problem, they released all the DLC map packs for free. So, now when you play you are able to play with everybody. Anyone who hasn't yet downloaded the free maps will probably get them in a later update. Hope this helps!!! :)